# Cannot assign value of type 'StorageReference' to type 'Storage!' ERROR

Tags: swift, firebase

When i write the line to upload or download with firebase i take this error. I am the new in swift please help me. Here is the code

```
var userStorage : Storage!

override func ViewDidLoad()

let storage = Storage.storage().reference(forURL: "gs://starz.appspot.com")
userStorage = storage.child("users")
```

So that is the error

> ------Cannot assign value of type 'StorageReference' to type 'Storage!'-------

Comment: Please include a [mcve] in your question to make it on-topic. For instance, how did you define `userStorage`?

Comment: Ohh sorry, It is edited now

Comment: Use var userStorage : StorageReference!

Comment: The error message is quite clear, your `userStorage` type annotation is wrong. Do `var userStorage : StorageReference!`.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/create-reference?hl=es-419